# Class variable resets to null when calling from another method in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a tabu search algorithm for a scheduling problem. The variable "Initialsequence" (which is declared static) resets its value to null when its called from a different method. 
the values in "Initialsequence" is populated in method "CreateInitialSolution()", and when i try to use it in another method"Create Neighborhood Solution()" the value is null. Can you please tell me why?

```
namespace TEST_CODE
{
    class Program
    {
        #region Parameters
        public static int No_mc;
        public static int No_prod;
        public static int Max_jobs;
        public static int[] No_jobs;
        public static int Tot_jobs;
        public static double[,] Run_time;
        public static double[, ,] Setup_time;
        public static double[] Setupst_time;
        public static double[,] Due_time;
        public static double[] Mc_avail_time;
        public static double[,] Job_release_time;
        public static int[] No_storage;
        public static double[] wt_product;
        public static double wt_producer;
        public static double wt_customer;
        public static double[][] tempDue_time;
        public static batch[,] Initialsequence;
        public static int BigM = 10000;

        #endregion Variables

        public class batch
        {
            public int Family { get; set; }
            public int Job { get; set; }
            public batch(int family, int job)
            {
                Family = family;
                Job = job;
            }
        }

 public static void CreateInitialSolution()
        {
            // CreateInitialSolution        
            int[] sequence = new int[Tot_jobs + 1];
            batch[,] Initialsequence = new batch[No_mc + 1, Tot_jobs + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < Tot_jobs; i++)
            {
                var min = tempDue_time.SelectMany((subArr, k) => subArr.Select((value, j) => new { k, j, value }))
                        .OrderBy(x => x.value)
                        .First();
                int firstIndex = min.k;
                int secondIndex = min.j;
                Initialsequence[1, i + 1] = new batch(firstIndex + 1, secondIndex + 1);
                tempDue_time[firstIndex][secondIndex] = BigM;
            }

            for (int i = 2; i <= No_mc; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= Tot_jobs; j++)
                {
                    Initialsequence[i, j] = Initialsequence[1, j];
                }
            }
        }

public static void CreateNeighborhoodSolution() 
        {
            // Create Neighborhood solution
            List<batch[,]> NSJ = new List<batch[,]>();

            for (int i = 1; i < Tot_jobs; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j <= Tot_jobs; j++)
                {
                    batch[,] Tempseq = new batch[No_mc + 1, Tot_jobs + 1];
                    Array.Copy(Initialsequence, Tempseq, Initialsequence.Length);
                    batch tempstr = new batch(Tempseq[1, i].Family, Tempseq[1, i].Job);
                    Tempseq[1, i] = Tempseq[1, j];
                    Tempseq[1, j] = tempstr;

                    for (int k = 2; k <= No_mc; k++)
                    {
                        for (int l = 1; l <= Tot_jobs; l++)
                        {
                            Tempseq[k, l] = Tempseq[1, l];
                        }
                    }
                    NSJ.Add(Tempseq);                   

                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mcve] as what you have provided is just a wall of code. I'm positive you can reduce this to a few lines...

Comment: Is this all of your code?  CreateInitialSolution() needs to be called before CreateNeighborhoodSolution() is called so that your static field is initialized.

Comment: No. This is just a part of the code. However, DavidG pointed out my mistake and the code works well now.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `CreateInitialSolution`, you are redefining the variable `Initialsequence`. This hides the class level variable. So change this:

```
batch[,] Initialsequence = new batch[No_mc + 1, Tot_jobs + 1];
```

To this:

```
Initialsequence = new batch[No_mc + 1, Tot_jobs + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are not actually initializing your `Program` class variable `Initialsequence` rather you are creating a local method variable of same name which gets out of scope once your method execution completes and thus the actual variable is still `null`. As pointed in below code block

```
 public static void CreateInitialSolution()
        {
            // CreateInitialSolution        
            batch[,] Initialsequence = new batch[No_mc + 1, Tot_jobs + 1];
```

SideNote: stop defining variable with same name which will lead you to confusion and others when you ask for help